# Server Not Found in Kerberos DataBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos

I am facing a problem regarding kerberos database connection.
I am unable to connect the kerberos database from another system where kerberos is not installed.
here are the logs while running from system on which kerberos is not installed

```
May 10 15:08:39 D-9539 krb5kdc[11882](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23})
 **10.10.179.228**: ISSUE: authtime 1462873119, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18  nses=18}, mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
May 10 15:08:40 D-9539 krb5kdc[11882](info): TGS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 10.10.179.228: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0,  mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM for **hbase/d-9539@EXAMPLE.COM**, **Server not found in Kerberos database**
```

Error:

```
Server not found in Kerberos database
```

and it is working fine on local machine that is where kerberos installed

logs while running locally on kerberos server

```
May 10 15:09:28 D-9539 krb5kdc[11882](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {18 17 16 23 1 3}) **10.10.167.160**: ISSUE: authtime 1462873168, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 
ses=18}, mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM for krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM

May 10 15:09:29 D-9539 krb5kdc[11882](info): TGS_REQ (6 etypes {18 17 16 23 1 3}) **10.10.167.160**: ISSUE: authtime 1462873168, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 
ses=18}, mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM for **hbase/d-9539.mydomain.com@EXAMPLE.COM**
```

One thing that i have noted is in above logs i am getting 
**for hbase/d-9539@EXAMPLE.COM**

```
d-9539 is not my FQDN
```

while in second log i am getting 
**for hbase/d-9539.mydomain.com@EXAMPLE.COM**

```
i.e d-9539.mydomain.com my FQDN
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have configured krb5.conf file properly in the client machine? It seems the error because of missing or invalid DNS entries.

[Some common Kerberos Error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/trouble-6/index.html)

Similar question here

[Cannot get Kerberos service ticket: KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850252/cannot-get-kerberos-service-ticket-krbexception-server-not-found-in-kerberos-d)

Comment: Thanks for the response i figured it out today,we have to set hbase.master.principal in configuration though i provided hbase-site.xml file but in xml file entry was _Host ,thus it was picking local host address i changed that _Host with FQDN

Answer (score 0):

dns issue

solution:

one:

edit /etc/hosts  map hbase/d-9539 hbase/d-9539

two:

if you use python paramiko client, can use param gss_trust_dns=False forbid host parse