# java 6u121 and kerberos

Tags: java, kerberos

Java **6u121** and **kerberos**

We encountered this error after upgrade to **6u121**. Does not happen in **6u31**. Also happens for **6u45**.

**No code available.**

```
 2019-07-19 16:00:29,405 DEBUG [http-8080-2] (DirectoryUtils.java:231)
 - javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by
 GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server
 not found in Kerberos database (7))]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get Kerberos service ticket: KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850252/cannot-get-kerberos-service-ticket-krbexception-server-not-found-in-kerberos-d)

Comment: Upgrade your Java version first.

Comment: Hi thanks. Unfortunately, we are unable to upgrade to higher version of java as it involve a lot of programming effort.